# cocos2d 1.0 beta transition between two scenes and the program just quit?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, selector, transition, schedule, scene

Hi am new to xcode and cocos2d development.  I have a question about switch scenes.  I have one class is called "GameScene" and has a schedule call "scheduleTarget" to add a target on the scene every 0.3 second.  When I switch from GameScene to GameOverScene or ManuScene using scene transition method, the program just quit without any error message.

I tried to clean up the memory by release the objects and call dealloc and onExit.

I also tried to unschedule the call "ScheduleTarget".  But nothing helps.

Anybody know what is my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem.  I assign the dealloc the variable a value. :(

I am so happy this issue has been solved.